# I can't download Android Studio from the web with Firefox Developer Edition

Tags: android-studio, firefox-developer-edition

### What I want to do !

I want to download Android Studio for developping app with Flutter on Windows.

### Expected result:

The download starts.

### Current result :

[image: Download Android Studio]

I'm French that's why you can't understand the message but it's an error saying that it's impossible to connect to the website.

#### Maybe a clue that'll help to solve that problem :

[image]

Comment: Just use another browser?

Comment: I just installed Firefox for installing Android Studio, before I used Opera and same result !

Comment: Well, I can't reproduce the issue. With Firefox and Chrome the download starts fine. Probably a DNS or any other network related issue on your side?

Comment: I don't have any problem with my network, I'll check my DNS. Honestly, I think this is weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank everyone, I found thanks to [Éder Rocha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6276911/%C3%89der-rocha).
This is a bug on Firefox and Opera that prevent you to download Android Studio with these browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In windows command line:

curl.exe --output android_studio.exe --url https://redirector.gvt1.com/edgedl/android/studio/install/4.1.3.0/android-studio-ide-201.7199119-windows.exe

Or try download using your browser directly via this link.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/p5fGS0E - Result (Spoil: Doesn't work but thanks)

Comment: And how about using your browser with this link?

Comment: It works as expected here. Maybe is something network related. Ask some friend to try it and let you know.

Comment: It worked on my IOS tablet, I’m gonna install Chrome in order to find out if it’s a bug of the others browsers.

If I find out what’s going on, I’ll let you know if you’re interested.

Even if it’s work the file can be used, this is a Mac OS file.

Comment: Try my link on your Tablet and it will download the .exe for Windows